# Laravel: Why should I use Middlewares?

Tags: php, laravel, view, middleware, laravel-artisan

For example in my User class I have an 'isAdmin' function which checks the role value of the user in the users table column, So I really don't see the need of using middlewares in this case. 
If I want to check if the user is the owner of a particular post in my application I will do something like this in my view:

```
@if(Auth::user()->id == $user->id) //$user is the passed user to the view
    <p>I am the owner of the post</p>
@elseif(Auth::guest())
    <p>I'm a visitor</p>
@else
    <p>I'm a registered user visiting this post</p>
```

Am i right or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: I am not a laravel expert, I started learning it 2 weeks ago, but I think you are not correct. Middlewares do things before anything else, if it does not fails, execution continues normally, or maybe you do some IP check, or proxy. I think your view is not right, you should check the `$post` (if this models exists, it should) owner/user_id like this `$post->user_id` or something like that.

Comment: https://philsturgeon.uk/php/2016/05/31/why-care-about-php-middleware/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the great benefits of middleware is that you can apply a set of logic to a [route group](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-groups) and not have to add that code to each controller method.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '/admin', 'middleware' => ['admin']], function () {
     // Routes go here that require admin access
});
```

And in the controller, you never have to add checks to see if they are an admin. They will only be able to access the route if they pass the middleware check.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.. So all of the routes which descended from **/admin** (EX: /admin/dashboard or /admin/userslist/blahblah) should pass the middleware before?

Comment: Yes, the route group will automatically do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

**Middleware** call before the call of controller action so it's used as a filter request or add external data which will not coming from request based on some condtion.

let's take one simple example.

```
@if(Auth::user()->id == $user->id) //$user is the passed user to the view
    <p>I am the owner of the post</p>
@elseif(Auth::guest())
    <p>I'm a visitor</p>
@else
    <p>I'm a registered user visiting this post</p>
```

if you want to show user is a owner,visitor or a guest,how many times you need to write a code ? i think in all **controller** or **view** so better than write a code in controller write in a **Middleware** and apply middleware to group of routes where you want to show.

in your middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
 {
    @if(Auth::user()->id == $user->id) 
    $user_type = "<p>I am the owner of the post</p>";
   @elseif(Auth::guest())
     $user_type = "<p>I'm a visitor</p>";
   @else
     $user_type = "<p>I'm a registered user visiting this post</p> ";

    $request -> attributes('user_type' => $user_type);

    return $next($request);
 }
```

So' now in your controller you can access `$user_type` and pass to view.

in your View

```
{{ $user_type }}
```